# RandomStringUtils - Not generating unique String for each test scenario

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am running a Selenium test and I'm trying to generate a different random String for each of my test scenarios, but I keep getting the same String.

Here is an example of what I'm running:

```
String randomString = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(8);

@Test(priority = 1)
private void testScenario_1(){
    System.out.println(randomString);
}

@Test(priority = 2)
private void testScenario_2(){
    System.out.println(randomString);
}
```

Comment: You are referring to the same randomString  in both of your Test. Bring String randomString = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(8); inside your @Test method

Comment: I'm sure a java expert could tell you more, but essentially you're setting the variable at the class level, which is only being created once. There's a good answer/solution below with a bit more detail.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible method would be to generate the random string in a `@BeforeMethod` annotated method.

```
String randomString = "";

@BeforeMethod
private void init() {
    randomString = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(8);
}

@Test(priority = 1)
private void testScenario_1() {
    System.out.println(randomString);
}

@Test(priority = 2)
private void testScenario_2() {
    System.out.println(randomString);
}
```

The method `init` will be called before each test method. One might think this is not needed in this case but if you have to do more preparations this is the way to go. You will reduce duplicate code.

Answer (score 0):

The same randomeString value is referred to in both of the tests. Move the generation of randomAlphabetic inside the test as below.

```
String randomString = "";

@Test(priority = 1)
private void testScenario_1(){
    randomString = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(8);
    System.out.println(randomString);
}

@Test(priority = 2)
private void testScenario_2(){
    randomString = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(8);
    System.out.println(randomString);
}
```